# A linearly Independent Set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_{n\times n}$ be a square matrix such that for some vector $v$ and positive integer $k$, $A^kv=0$ and  $A^{k-1}v\not=0$. Then prove that $v, Av, A^2v,...,A^{k-1}v$ are Linearly Independent. And what could be the Jordan of $ A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $$\lambda_1v+\lambda_2 Av+\dots +\lambda_{k}A^{k-1}v=0.$$
Applying $A^{k-1}$ to both sides yields
$$\lambda_1A^{k-1}v=0.$$
Since $A^{k-1}v\neq 0$ we must have that $\lambda_1=0$, thus 
$$\lambda_2 Av+\dots +\lambda_{k}A^{k-1}v=0.$$
Applying $A^{k-2}$ yields $$\lambda_2A^{-1}v=0.$$ Again we conclude that $\lambda_2=0$. Continuing in this fashion gives that $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i$. Thus they are linearly independent.

As for the Jordan form, notice that $\ker(A^k)\neq \left\{0\right\}$. What does this tell you?

Comment: the Jordan too, please